# PostgreSQL DAO.java method to get single int value

Tags: java, hibernate, select, dao

This is the method I'm using:

```
  public int getId(String proyectName)
    {
      
      int idproyect=0;
      

        
        try
        {
            Session session= hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  
            String hql = "Select idproyect from proyect where name= :proyectName";
             Query query = session
                        .createQuery(hql);
             query.setParameter("proyectName", proyectName);
             idproyect= (Integer)query.uniqueResult();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        

        }
        return idproyect;
    }
```

No matter the variable is being inyected into the method the result I'm getting is 0 which matches with the idproyect default value.
I checked my logs and the select is being executed but the result is still 0, no matter what.
I think It has to do with the query conversion into Integer unique value.
This problem has concerned me for like 2 days but I ignored until today because I need to solve it to carry on with my project.

I don't think its relevant but I'm using Hibernate to persist the classes.

Comment: Why is your exception handler empty? Add an `e.printStackTrace()` there and add the results to your question.

Comment: True fact, but im still not getting any error tho.

Answer (score 0):

you try this to get single int value

```
  String hql = "Select idproyect from proyect where name= :proyectName";
  Query query2 = entitymanager.createNativeQuery(hql).setParameter("proyectName", proyectName);
    BigInteger obj = (BigInteger) query2.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("%%%%%%%" + obj);
    System.out.println(obj);
    long id = Long.valueOf(obj.toString()));
    System.out.println(id);
```

Comment: I checked Logs and Im getting this : java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode